# Among 10 sites that I open them daily, Stackoverflow is the fastest one, How you made that?

Tags: discussion, performance, web, web-hosting

I knew this question might be more technical, but amazing to know at least some background information about hosting model and how a dynamic site with millions of users can be navigated very fast...

Also, with slow Internet Line, I can always navigate SO without any problem :)

Can you please explain how you made that?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters: but we also knew about them, what is amazing here how these system integrated that makes the site very fast :)

Comment: Caching...the answers is always caching.

Comment: (lots of server power) + (efficient coding) + (minified resources) + (tons of caching) = what you see. :)

Comment: Google's indexing has nothing to do with SO itself. It's just that the site is popular and frequently "updated", so Google pays attention.

Comment: I thought about caching, but each page and post has variables such as votes, comments, status update! then I think its a power of juqery somehow and ajax

Comment: @phwd: why you deleted the image?

Comment: @Bart: I will be wrong, but fast indexing by google indicating a connection between SO and Google :) I love to see became partner

Comment: There is no connection between Google and Stack Exchange. Google's algorithm just *loves* sites that are frequently updated with lots of new content. That's what we do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are fanatical about performance - everything boils down to that.  Every day we look for ways to improve.

- Can we not run a query here?
- Can we consolidate queries?
- Can we extend this index to cover 20% more cases?
- Can we denormalize this data to eliminate a join?
- Can we stick this in redis?
- *Should* we stick this in redis?
- Should we aggregate this into a central DB?
- Can we eliminate this API call?
- Is JSON right here?
- How about Protobuf?
- Can we not do an allocation here?
- Can we completely change how this is cached and accessed?
- Is this hit often enough to rewrite it in IL?
- How about we just replace the ORM?

...these are daily questions around here.  It's a culture thing, and we love it.

Edit: I am preparing an architecture overview for our upcoming Velocity talk in October, we'll be sure to share it when done - for those that are curious.

Comment: That what I expected, there is no linear system for fast performance, the hardware and integration plays a part in performance, but optimization is also great when the site viewed by millions of user :)

Comment: We control all the hardware and software - so how we setup the network bonds, tweak the TCP buffers, layout security so low-latency queries need not pass a router, etc...it all plays a part, it just adds up.  I should write a post on everything we do in the name of performance (it's a long, long list), just have to find the time.

Comment: Don't forget Unicorn dust. It really speeds things up.